# ASP.NET Core 2.0 static files, but .html doesn't work?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core-2.0

This is making me tear my hair out. I'm trying to create a minimal ASP.NET core 2.0 app, so I create an empty web application in VS 2017, and I run:

```
> uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.All
> install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore
> install-package Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles
```

My `Startup.cs` looks like:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.Run(async (context) =>
        {
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("Hello World!");
        });
    }
}
```

I then create a `wwwroot/test.html` with these contents:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>HTML</h1>
    <p>Hello world!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

I then create a `wwwroot/test.txt` with the same contents as test.html. So this appears to be is a bare bones setup that should serve any static files under `wwwroot` for over 400 known MIME types.

Now when I run this project with F5, it opens to the root URL and displays "Hello World!" as expected, indicating it hit the "terminal middleware delegate". If you add `/test.txt` to the URL you get the HTML displayed above, again as expected. If you change the URL to `/test.html` you do not get the HTML file as expected, but instead the standard "Hello World!" message.

I've tried this on two separate machines, same results. Now stop debugging, change `test.html` to `test.htm`, try again and `test.htm` works as expected!

An insane thought occurred to me, that perhaps they simply didn't associate .html with "text/html" in the `FileExtensionContentTypeProvider`, but nope, [there it is](https://github.com/aspnet/StaticFiles/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles/FileExtensionContentTypeProvider.cs#L122). I even tried creating a custom type provider explicitly with this association, but that didn't work either.

Can anyone clue me in as to what is going on here? Or am I the only one going insane here and this example works fine for everyone else?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x&view=aspnetcore-2.1

Comment: Static files are working fine except for .html. How about actually providing helpful feedback.

Comment: How did you create the file? I've just created a new project and can't reproduce the problem. The .html extension works, everything else returns the Hello World message.

Comment: You say the file is called test.html, but in your description of the URL, you've written text.html.

Comment: I created the file in visual studio, like any other file. It can't be related to the file itself, because if I rename the extension it works. This originally happened in another project, and I started a whole new project to reproduce the problem. I have another thought since you created a project, go into the project properties > Debug panel. In the App URL where it says something like http://localhost:56945/, add test.html on the end and try that. It's a mistake that breaks it, but even after removing it, I think it leaves .html static files broken.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I fixed the typo in the post. That's not the issue.

Comment: Can't reproduce it either. What is the exact version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions everyone, I reviewed the procedure and discovered the actual source of the problem and posted a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to greg84's comment above, I retraced my steps and I know how everything got borked. I had gone into the project properties > Debug panel to setup the default launch URL, but at one point I mistakenly added `/test.html` to the "App URL" parameter, so it looked like "http://localhost:57661/test.html".

After realizing that I had actually intended to add it to the "Launch Browser" section, I corrected that, but damage already done. The `.vs/applicationhost.config` had already stored it as a **second** application/virtualDirectory mapping, which broke all references to test.html.

Of course, these settings are not actually visible anywhere as I was investigating, so I chugged along only getting broken behaviour on my single .html page which made absolutely no sense to me.

And of course, moving the project to a second machine simply carried the .vs/applicationhost.config file with it, so the same behaviour appeared.

Thanks for the suggestions everyone!